# C# Labels(altering label color)

Tags: c#, winforms, label

In a windows form application, i have six text boxes with labels on them. each label shows the date starting from monday to saturday. There are also buttons to navigate to the previous and next weeks respectively.
I want to be able to highlight in RED the current date each time i load the from. Though i've managed to achieve this, each time i click the next/previous button the label still remains coloured. For example if current date is 29 November Thursday (highlighted in RED), clicking the next button would show 06 December Thursday on that label but also highlighted in red which is wrong because 06 December Thursday isn't the current date. Any ideas how i can solve this problem? Here is my code for altering label color. Thanks

```
         if (label1.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        else label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         if (label2.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
             label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
         else label2.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         if (label3.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
             label3.BackColor = Color.Red;
         else label3.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         if (label4.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
            label4.BackColor = Color.Red;
         else label4.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         if (label5.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
            label5.BackColor = Color.Red;
         else label5.ForeColor = Color.Black;

         if (label6.Text == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd"))
            label6.BackColor = Color.Red;
         else label6.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: use the debugger to ensure that what you think is happening, actually is happening.  http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: is this wpf? why you don't use binding?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: "In a Windows form application..."

Comment: Simple, your test always returns true. Now you just have to find out why by using debugging tools. (Breakpoint before any test and check your labelX.text). Also if you're using the `BackColor` property, the text won't change.

Comment: @dhani: Why are you mixing `BackColor` and `ForeColor`? `BackColor` is the background color of the `TextBox`, and `ForeColor` is the text color inside the `TextBox`. You should *only* be using one or the other consistently.

Comment: Is it me or didnt you want "dd MMMM dddd" to be more like "dd MMMM yyyy"  ??

Comment: @CSharpie not if he wants the date number, the full name of the month, the full name of the day and doesn't need the year. (Altough it is highly possible he wanted the year instead)

Comment: @CSharpie I didn't want the year just wanted date, month and day of week

Answer (score 7):

I think problem is that you are mixing `BackColor` and `ForeColor` setting. Remove duplicated logic and apply style in same way in one place. Create methods

```
private void ApplyStyleTo(Label label)
{
    label.ForeColor = GetLabelForeColor(label.Text);
}

private Color GetLabelForeColor(string text)
{
    string todayText = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM dddd");
    return (text == todayText) ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
}
```

And apply styles to all labels:

```
ApplyStyleTo(label1);
// ...
ApplyStyleTo(label6);
```

---

**BTW** Actully I'd go further and created custom label for displaying date. Place these labels on your form and set their `Date` property like this:

```
dateLabel1.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Label will format and colorize date. You will be able to change date format and colors.

```
public class DateLabel : Label
{
    private DateTime? _date;

    public DateLabel()
    {
        Format = "dd MMMM dddd";
        TodayForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set {
            _date = value;
            Text = _date.HasValue ? _date.Value.ToString(Format) : "";
            ForeColor = IsToday ? TodayForeColor : ForeColor;
        }
    }

    public bool IsToday
    {
        get  {
            if (!_date.HasValue)
                return false;    
            return _date.Value.Date == DateTime.Today;
        }
    }

    public string Format { get; set; }
    public Color TodayForeColor { get; set; }
}
```